# Alternativa assíncrona para Thread.Sleep sem travar aplicação em C#

Tags: c#, thread, assincronismo

As vezes queremos que nossa aplicação aguarde alguns momentos para prosseguir com a próxima instrução, porém o **Thread.Sleep(0)** pode causar travamentos em sua aplicação, principalmente utilizando em loops.
Por isso, aqui vai uma dica de como aguardar um período que desejar sem causar nenhum travamento da aplicação.

Answer (score 3):

Defina uma variável booleana:

```
bool await;
```

Crie um objeto **Windows Timer** com nome(*exemplo*) awaitTimer, e no seu Evento Tick adicione o seguinte código:

```
private void awaitTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    awaitTimer.Stop();
    await = false;
}
```

Crie um método, aqui vamos chamar de **Await**:

```
public void Await(int interval)
{
    await = true;
    awaitTimer.Interval = interval;
    awaitTimer.Start();
    while (await)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

Para utilizar, bastar digitar Await(*), entre parenteses colocar o tempo que desejar esperar para a próxima instrução em milissegundos.

```
//Events

Await(1000); //1000 para esperar 1 segundo

//Events
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode obter o mesmo resultado sem o uso do timer:

```
public void Await(int milliseconds)
{
    DateTime dateTimeTarget = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(milliseconds);

    while (DateTime.Now < dateTimeTarget)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

Veja também o método [Task.Delay()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netframework-4.7.2) a partir do .Net Framework 4.5

Comment: excelente vik, muito obrigado! :)